# place a div upon another div

Tags: html, css

here is my how i want the website design to be : [image: Design]

so i am in the initial step, my query is how do i place the slider div upon the header div and i want it to be in the centre. my code what i have used is :

```
<div id="header">
<div class="slider">
</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>


body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background:#fff;
}

#header
{
    background:#859685;
    height:300px;

}

.slider
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    position:absolute;
z-index:1;
width:980px;
height:200px;
border: 4px #666 solid;  
}

.content
{
    margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-top:10px;
  width:980px;
  height:400px;
  background:#fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.footer
{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
padding: 0;
height:300px;
background:#98AFC7;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background:#111312;
}
```

here is my fiddle jsfiddle.net/hdmep/

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/hdmep/3/)
I changed the sizes a little bit (so it'll look nice in the Fiddle)

this is all about absolute positioning.

also if you're just going to use background for color, use `background-color` instead of `background`
and, notice the short way of using `margin` for all sides at once.

**CSS:**

```
#header
{
    background-color: #859685;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative; /*the slider is now relative to the header*/
}
.slider
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 80%; /*80% of header*/
    height: 50%; /* 50% of header*/
    border: 4px #666 solid;
    top: 70%;
    left: 10%;
}
.content
{
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: azure;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.footer
{
    margin: 10px 0;
    height: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #111312;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your slider class to something like this:

```
.slider
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;      
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-top:250px;
    position:absolute;
    width:980px;
    height:200px;
    border: 4px #666 solid;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MPNq6/1/)

update slider class:

```
.slider {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    bottom: -150px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 980px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 4px #666 solid;
}
```